# How to save and read tar.gz files in Android?

Tags: android

I'm getting a tar.gz file from a server. Using retrofit I got the response checked using Charles proxy. Now, how can I store the response in the internal storage and read the file content? The tar.gz file has PNG files. Below is the code snippet where I'm getting the response from the server.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(builder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://www.labox.com/")
            .build();

    HttpService downloadService = retrofit.create(HttpService.class);

    downloadService.downloadChannelLogoZipFile(URI)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<File>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<File> call(final Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super File> subscriber) {
                            try {
....}
```